# Folder "named" suddenly appeared inside C:\Users\

Tags: windows-7, windows

Checking properties, it appears to have been created about 9 days ago.

Inside, it contains the usual contents of a typical user folder in Windows 7:

[image]

I see no user "named" when I checked `Control Panel > User Accounts`.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: try `net users` in command prompt. See if there is a 'hidden' user called named.

Comment: @mt025 well apparently there is! possible hack?

Comment: More likely created by an application. Not sure why it's called named. The contents of the appdata folder may give hints to what application created it. Look for folders other than Microsoft. I'm sure there will be a way to find out what it's doing. Maybe in the event log.

Comment: Upon checking it contains these
`C:\Users\named\AppData\Local\Google`
`C:\Users\named\AppData\Local\Micorosft`
`C:\Users\named\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft`
`C:\Users\named\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia` (WTF macomedia haven't heard that in years)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the number of your user accounts (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage Accounts) is the same as the account when you run net users command.
Sometimes, user changed there user name in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change an Account -> Change the account name, but the name only appear on the Welcome screen and on the Start menu, the user profile folder name won’t be changed.